# Limit of $\sum_1^\infty n^\alpha e^{- n^\alpha}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $\alpha > 1$.
The series $\sum_1^\infty n^\alpha e^{- n^\alpha}$ is convergent (using the ratio test for example).

Is there a way to compute its sum ?

**Edit**: or maybe a upper bound of its sum ? My ultimate goal is to show the finiteness of $\int_0^1 \sum_1^\infty n^\alpha e^{-t n^\alpha} \,\mathrm{d}t$

Comment: Don't know about the sum, but the integral $\int_0^{\infty} n^{\alpha}e^{-n^{\alpha}}dn= \frac{1}{\alpha}\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{\alpha}+1\right),$ so it's "close" to that.

Comment: In closed form?  Almost certainly not in general, although the case $\alpha=2$ can be expressed in terms of Jacobi theta functions.

Comment: @RobertIsrael in fact, an upper bound might be enough (see my edit concerning what I truly want to achieve)

Comment: Let $q$ be any integer exceeding $\alpha$. Then your sum is bounded by $\sum n^qe^{-n}$, and that sum can be computed in closed form.

Comment: Integrate first, then sum.  But it isn't finite.

Comment: Did it work, P. C?

Comment: @GerryMyerson yes for this question but I was trying to achieve something more general, I've asked another question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3219398/finiteness-of-integral-and-convergence-of-series